# batch email send with custom content

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I want to send out batch mails using SwiftMailer but just wondering what the best option for this would be. The problem is the email content needs to be customized, i.e. there will be a salutation at the top, and a custom link.

Here is my current OOP code:

```
foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
{
    $quote=new Quote();
    $quote->enquiry_id=$enquiry->id;
    $quote->supplier_id=$supplier->id;

    if($quote->save())
    {
        $supplier_emails[]=$supplier->email;
    }
}

$message=new SwiftMailMessage;
$message->setTo($supplier_emails);
$message->setFrom($params['adminEmailFromAddress'] => $params['adminEmailFromName']);
$message->setBody('Here is the message itself')
App::app()->mail->batchSend($message);
```

I am using a container for SwiftMailer. So as you can see, I can easily specify an array of email address to send the message to. How can I now customize the content? The variables I need to include in the content are $supplier->name and $supplier->link.

Personally I can't see how this can be done, other than sending each email individually in the foreach() loop. IF that is the case, then is it not better to just use the internal PHP mail() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the Decorator plugin:

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/decorator-plugin

Comment: Interesting, I didn't see that. I'll probably give that a go, but I noticed on the site the author has written: "While the decorator plugin provides a means to solve this problem, there are various ways you could tackle this problem without the need for a plugin." - any suggestions on this?

Comment: Well, to me this seems to be the easiest solution. You can even provide your own Replacements Lookup function for it.